# Laravel validate regex not allow kanji char

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I want to validate a form input which not allow input kanji char using Laravel validate rule.
How to do it?
This is what I did:

```
public function validationRules()
{
    return [
        ‘name’ => 'regex:/[^\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]+/u'
    ];
}
```

But this work only when all char are kanji. If one of char is not kanji then the regex return valid.

actually now:

ひらがなカタカナ漢字　=> valid

123abc => valid

ひらがなカタカナ => valid

漢字 =>  not valid

what I want:

ひらがなカタカナ漢字　=> not valid

123abc => valid

ひらがなカタカナ => valid

漢字 => not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is final script resolve this case:

```
function isKatakana($value){
    return preg_match('/[\x{3040}-\x{309f}\x{4e00}-\x{9faf}]/u', $value)?false:true;
}
```